# What are the difference between `pushManager.subscribe` and `pushManager.getSubscription` Service Worker's

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, push-api

> **PushManager.getSubscription()**
>
> Retrieves an existing push subscription. It returns a Promise that resolves to a PushSubscription object containing details of an existing subscription. If no existing subscription exists, this resolves to a null value.

[...]

> PushManager.subscribe()
>
> Subscribes to a push service. It returns a Promise that resolves to a PushSubscription object containing details of a push subscription. A new push subscription is created if the current service worker does not have an existing subscription.

According to MDN's `pushManager` documentation. There methods are pretty much the same, except the point that in case of `getSubcription()` it may resolved with a null value.

I am basically understand that I can simply use `subscribe()` and Service Worker will try to get the subscription in case it available, and also create new one in case it not available.

=> But I was trying to do something else. I want to try to get subscription first, if it resolved with `null` I will try to subscribe it.

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./worker.js')
    .then(function(reg) {

        // Subscribe push manager
        reg.pushManager.getSubscription()
        .then(function(subscription) {

            if(subscription){
                // TODO... get the enpoint here
            } else {
                reg.pushManager.subscribe()
                .then(function(sub){
                    // TODO... get the endpoint here
                });
            }

        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        })
    });
```

But then I am ended up with the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Subscription failed - no active Service Worker

It is confusing, and I am doubting this is a limitation of Chrome on Push API of Service Worker or can possibly a bug. Does any one has any information about this strange behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your service worker is registered, but it isn't active yet.

You can use [navigator.serviceWorker.ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/ready) instead of subscribing right after registering the service worker.

If you want to make the service worker active as soon as possible, you can use [skipWaiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting) and [Clients.claim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim), as described in [this ServiceWorker Cookbook recipe](https://serviceworke.rs/immediate-claim.html).